# How do I rename column in delta table

Tags: databricks

I'm trying to rename a column of my delta table.So I wrote following code

```
%sql
alter table mytable 
rename column oldName to neName
```

But I'm getting error message

```
missing 'TO' at 'column'
```

Can you let me know the correct statement?

Comment: try this ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN col_old_name col_new_name

Comment: Check out this https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html

Comment: @AbuShoeb, the above is only working for Hive table, not Delta table